# Uncaught ReferenceError: multiselect is not defined

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I use boostrap for an multiselect element.
I want unselect an opion but I have this error:

```
antinsfw:222 Uncaught ReferenceError: multiselect is not defined
at cancel (antinsfw:222)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (antinsfw:172)
```

Full code of my page: https://haste.flo-x.fr/urutonelay.xml.

elements concerned:

```
<select class="selectpicker border-gray txt-gray bg-dark" title="select an channel" id="multi-select" multiple>
  {% for channel in channel %}
  <option id="option_multidict" value={{channel[0]}} class="bg-dark txt-gray" {% if channel[0]|string in position %} selected {% endif %}>{{channel[1][:14]}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

and js code:

```
jQuery('selectpicker').multiselect('deselect', ['1']);
```

Thanks for you answers!

Comment: Not sure it will your problem, but your missing a "." to select a class and not an element. Should be jQuery('.selectpicker').

Comment: no, it doesn't fix the problem :(

Comment: Hi, its `.selectpicker` or `.multiselect` ?

Comment: .selectpicker :)

Comment: Ho, if I do: `jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselect', '0');` its work !!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselect', '0');` and it works.